# Употребление тире в газетных статьях

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

Я являюсь иностранной студенткой, изучающей русский язык. Хотелось бы узнать, по каким правилам в данных предложениях было употреблено тире:

1) Но здесь в зависимости от склада личности – возможны разные, порой противоположные варианты, и мы их знаем.

2) Нет, пушкинские слова «мы ленивы и нелюбопытны» – о ком угодно, только не о нем…

3) Те, у кого пары сотен тысяч евро на покупку шенгенского подданства не было, — ограничивались непременными поездками.

4) Предполагается, что на полную загрузку новые трубы (суммарная мощность составляет 86,5 млрд куб. м в год. – «Ведомости») могут быть выведены к концу следующего года.

Заранее извиняюсь, если мои вопросы банальны. Однако, самостоятельно у меня не получилось найти ответы в справочнике по орфографии и пунктуации под редакцией Лопатина.

Comment: После номера пункта обязательно пробел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я коротко выскажу свое мнение.

Да, существует так называемое **интонационное тире**, которое не связано с грамматикой предложения.

Но это не значит, что тире можно ставить где угодно и как угодно. Постановка тире должна быть **обоснованной**, так как это тире обозначают паузу, а пауза меняет расстановку логических ударений в предложении.

Если ничего этого нет, то мы получим не интонационное тире, а "графическое", то есть письменный, а не интонационный знак. А таких знаков в правилах русского языка нет.

Я думаю, что что в первых двух предложениях тире поставлено неверно, в третьем предложении постановка тире зависит от контекста, а оформление четвертого предложения лучше проверить редакторам.

**Возможное редактирование:**

1) *Но здесь – **в зависимости от склада личности** – возможны разные, порой противоположные варианты, и мы их знаем.*

2) *Нет, пушкинские слова – **«мы ленивы и нелюбопытны»** – о ком угодно, только не о нем…*

3) *Те, у кого пары сотен тысяч евро на покупку шенгенского подданства не было, — ограничивались непременными поездками.*

Здесь постановка тире зависит от контекста. Тире ставится при описании "параллельных" ситуаций, например,  когда дается информация о действиях разных лиц (одни делали так, другие иначе).

Comment: Касательно 3 предложения, полная версия звучит так: _Граждане, высидевшие себе в бизнесе и при казне пресловутые "деньги на старость", массово приобретали шенгенские паспорта (особенно упоенно ими торговали, как мы помним, Прибалтика и Кипр). Те, у кого пары сотен тысяч евро на покупку шенгенского подданства не было, — ограничивались непременными поездками._ Если ссылаться на параллелизм, то по какому правилу конкретно (учитывая, что это два самостоятельных предложения)?

Comment: Касательно 2 предложения, нельзя ли его рассматривать в качестве неполного с пропущенным сказуемым, например, "сказаны/написаны" и ставить лишь одно тире после "нелюбопытны"? Прим. данное сказуемое из контекста не восстанавливается

Comment: Пушкинские слова «мы ленивы и нелюбопытны» – о ком угодно, только не о нем…  Если убрать НЕТ, то  предложение можно считать эллиптическим. Это двусоставные предложения, где сказуемого нет, но оно подразумевается (написаны, сказаны и т.д.). Тогда тире можно поставить, интонационным его в этом случае не называют. В таких предложениях   тире зависит от паузы, а пауза здесь  возможна. А чем нам помешало слово  НЕТ? Дело в том, что эллиптическое предложение двухчастное, а НЕТ приходится обособлять (это уже три части). См. Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93  (пункт 1).

Comment: В тоже время вариант без паузы в эллиптических предложениях тоже возможен. Тогда нужно смотреть контекст: как предложение лучше читается, как вписывается в общий текст (с паузой или без паузы).

Comment: Извиняюсь, но я одна вижу ошибку в справочниках при отсылке друг на друга? В Розентале в п.1 ссылаются на параграф 16 в Лопатине, хотя по логике должна быть отсылка к параграфу 18, не так ли?

Comment: Если же отталкиваться от того, что п.1 в справочнике Розенталя эквивалентен 18 параграфу в справочнике Лопатина (http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg18.php), то можно ли данное предложение, если убрать _нет_, рассматривать как эллиптическое? В Лопатине говорится, что такое предложение распадается на 2 части - подлежащную и обстоятельственную, а в этом же предложении подлежащная и дополнение

Comment: Я бы рекомендовала бы Вам заниматься по справочнику Розенталя. Он более полный и, как мне кажется, более авторитетный. Правила ПАС значительно упрощены, также встречаются некоторые несоответствия по сравнению с Розенталем. Для справок. Розенталь - автор многих трудов по правописанию, а Лопатин  в 2001 году хотел провести реформу, упрощающую русское письмо, но она не была утверждена. Что касается эллиптических предложений, то в ПАС они кратко рассмотрены в параграфе 17, но эллиптическими не  называются У Розенталя это п. 1. в пар. 16.  Схема вашего предложения: Пушкинские слова - о ком угодно.

Comment: Благодарю. Можно ли еще получить ответ касательно предложения 3? См. мой первый комментарий

Comment: В этом предложении ставится интонационное тире, а оно в общем случае обозначает авторскую паузу, а в каждом конкретном случае имеет свое объяснение. В данном случае тире подчеркивает смысловую связь предложений в плане параллельных ситуаций, иначе эта связь может остаться незамеченной, так как предложения значительно распространены. Что касается самих параллельных  конструкций, то ни упоминаются, к примеру, при анализе неполных предложений у Розенталя: пар. 6, п. 2. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

Comment: Во втором примере тире вполне корректно. Пропущено сказуемое "можно говорить". Ещё тире интонационно подчёркивает отрицание. Да и после тире можно подставить слово "это". Это тот случай, когда несколько факторов способствуют тире. И никак нельзя разрывать "слова" с примером самих слов. Сравнить:  *Нет, слово (—) "лентяй" – о ком угодно, только не о нём.*

Answer (score 0):

1-3 — интонационное тире. Используется, если автор желает сделать акцент на чём-то. То есть оно не обязательно. Тире в этих примерах можно и не использовать.
Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94

4 — там после тире указан источник информации. Его же нужно отделить от самой информации. Тире больше всего подходит.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Однако, у меня все-таки возникают сомнения насчет 1 предложения, а конкретно: не является ли "в зависимости от склада личности" обособленным оборотом? Которое по правилам должно с двух сторон отделяться запятыми, а не одиночным тире?

Comment: Касательно 4 предложения хотелось бы также получить более подробную информацию. Считается ли постановка данного тире нормативной? Самостоятельный поиск в справочнике не дал результата, т.к. данный комментарий, вставленный в предложение, не является цитатой (по крайней мере не оформлен как цитата - отсутствуют кавычки)

Comment: Обособленный оборот отделяется с двух сторон. Тогда перед "в" был бы знак. Но этот оборот является центральным элементом смысла. Его незачем обосабливать. Обособление обычно, когда оборот в середине предложения: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_800 || Нельзя судить о нормативности, когда лучше тире варианта нет. Но здесь по смыслу после тире подходит слово "это", перед которым ставится тире: *(это сообщают) "Ведомости"*. Другое дело, что такое указание источника выглядит странным. Обычно добавляют "по материалам" или "по данным".

Comment: К предложению 3 у меня также остались вопросы. Возможно ли вообще данное тире рассматривать как выделительное? Ссылаюсь на справочник Лопатина (правило 21), в котором сказано, что тире ставится для подчеркивания _поясняющих_ членов предложения. Однако, в данном случае это не поясняющий член, а сказуемое.

Comment: А в § 21 как раз про интонационное тире - оно ведь выполняет именно функцию выделения.

Comment: Лучше читать Розенталя. Справочник Лопатина очень лаконичный - без подробностей, исключений, примечаний. Там всего по чуть-чуть.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что оно выполняет функцию выделения. Однако, меня смущает формулировка данного правила, а именно: Тире ставится перед членами предложения для их акцентирования. Такие члены предложения называются присоединительными. Однако, в 3 предложении тире стоит не перед присоединительным членом, а перед _сказуемым_, поэтому это вызывает у меня вопрос

Comment: Просто для подчёркивания сказуемого. Тире ставится не просто так. При чтении там должна быть соответствующая пауза и усиленная интонация.

Comment: "Такие члены предложения называются присоединительными." - не совсем понятно, что здесь имеется в виду. Но интонационное тире вполне может стоять перед сказуемым. Пример Розенталя перед подлежащим: *Через несколько минут загремели цепи, двери отворились, и вошёл — Швабрин.*

Comment: Наверное, элементы после тире интонационно присоединяются. Там ведь пауза делается - даже перед сказуемым. А пауза - своего рода рассоединение.